# Are efflux pumps mutations or are they originally present in N. gonorrhoea?

Tags: bacteriology, mutations

I'll start by saying that I am no biologist. I am a math major trying to create a mathematical model for gonorrhea strain competition. My assignment is to create a model similar to a model that was already was already created, see page 9 of [Evolution of within-host Antibiotic Resistance in Gonorrhea](http://mtbi.asu.edu/files/Evolution_of_within-host_Antibiotic_Resistance_in_Gonorrhea.pdf).

I wanted to try to incorporate the efflux pump into a mathematical model. Before I do that, I would first like to see whether efflux is gained through mutations. If it is, my model will be pointless since mutations are already covered in the original model from the research paper.

Feel free to add better tags. I thought mine was appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Efflux pumps](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efflux_(microbiology)) are common in bacteria, as well as eukaryotes. The mutations included in their model would not include efflux pumps. A mutation could potentially affect the efficiency of a pump in a strain but the mutations in their model are not creating the pumps.